# Merge two databases: OLD SITE -> NEW SITE

Tags: database

I am working to a restyle of a website.

I made DB dump from remote server and made local installation, then started to work on my local machine.

While i've been working other post have been added to remote site, so database has new entry that i missed.

Now i need to put online my restyled site and integrate the new entries in my DB. How can i do this?
Using Export/import tool would overwrite my new DB?

NOTE: The structure of new db is completely alterated from the old one: got new Post-type, categories, custom fields, ecc...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the export/import feature visit [Tools Export Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen).

Comment: Does exported file overwrites my new structure?

Comment: It shouldn't but backup your new databases before doing this, just in case something else goes wrong with the import.

Comment: A sure way to test if your file will be overwritten is to set up a testing environment on your localhost, export your new DB, set up a new WP install on your machine, import the old db and see if your data is changed, erased or unaffected.

Comment: There is a new plugin : **Versionpress** https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243047/4217721